# powers of ideals in quadratic fields

Tags: number-theory

Let $\mathfrak{a}=(4,\sqrt{-23})$ be an ideal in $\mathcal{O_K}$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$. Is there a way how to easy calculate $\mathfrak{a}^{22}=\mathfrak{a}\cdot...\cdot\mathfrak{a}$?

Comment: Also posted to (and closed on) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359452/power-of-ideals-in-quadratic-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your ideal is the trivial ideal $(1)$, so so is its 22nd power.

If this was not the case you can use the structure of the ideal class group which is the group of non-zero fractional ideals quotiented by the subgroup consisting of only the principal fractional ideals.

For $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-23})$ this group is the cyclic group of order $3$, which means that given any $\mathfrak a$ the third power $\mathfrak a^3$ is a principal ideal.

So  to compute the 22nd power more easily for example you can calculate $\mathfrak a^3$ which is of the form $(\alpha)$ and then $\mathfrak a^{22} = \mathfrak a \cdot \mathfrak a ^{21} =\mathfrak a \cdot (\alpha^7)$, which should be far easier to calculate.

Comment: since $1=6\times4+\sqrt{-23}\times\sqrt{-23}$?     at first glance, I thought it was something like $(2,1+\sqrt{−5})$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$

Comment: thanks for the help.  Is there also a way how to calculate $\mathfrak{a}^{22}$ where $\mathfrak{a}$ is not $\mathcal{O_K}$?

Comment: @user784236 I edited my answer to explain another approach when the ideal is non-trivial.